# Default category isn't saved in database

Tags: categories

We have set WordPress to assign a default category to new posts, as it does anyway by default.
Yet, when I check in the database, there is no category set on e.g. a post I just created. Is this because WordPress adds this just via code, and not in the database?

I have a filter which shows posts based on some categories, and when the category isn't set in the database, the post isn't showing.

Is there something wrong, or do I have to find a way to work around this?

EDIT:
The problem is that the category set as the default category doesn't appear on the posts in the database. Because of that, I can't filter posts by it.

Comment: I typically just rename uncategorized to the category I want it to be the default one, as uncategorized is the default category.

Comment: @gdaniel The problem is that the category set as the default category doesn't appear on the posts in the database. Because of that, I can't filter posts by it.

Comment: Where in the database are you checking? you should be able to find all the categories/terms under wp_terms, and the relationship between categories/terms and posts in the wp_term_relationships table.

Comment: If I run this query `select * from wp_term_relationships where object_id = 1234;`, and `1234` is the post id, I would get no results. There are no entries in the `wp_term_relationships` table for that post. Do I have to create a workaround for this?

Comment: you might be having other issues then, I just checked and after creating a new post, and adding it to the uncategorized category, I see the relationship created in the wp_term_relationships table.

Comment: @gdaniel Thanks for the feedback, that is helpful to know. I'll start looking at that!

Comment: @ptf, did you figure out what the issue is?

Comment: @guiniveretoo I think I did, though not how to solve it. I use ACF custom fields to save the categories, and it doesn't save the default category when no categories is selected. This is my post on the ACF forums: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/taxonomy-field-option-save-terms-prevents-default-category-saving/